# How can I get my drush aliases into the ddev web container?

Tags: drupal, drush, ddev

I use `drush rsync` and other things that interact with my drush aliases, and so need to have my drush aliases in the ddev web container. How can I do that? It would be a shame to copy them all in there or have them in my project.

Answer (score 5):

For drush aliases stored in ~/.drush/aliases on the host, you can add a .ddev/docker-compose.drush.yaml with these contents:

```html
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - "$HOME/.drush/aliases:/home/.drush/aliases"
```

Then run `ddev start` and your aliases will be in the web container's user home.